# Meaning of 'precipice' in the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

What is the meaning of precipice in the sentence below and also the complete meaning of the sentence?

I believe precipice has negative connotations attached  to it- a precarious condition or a situation of great peril. But in the given sentence 'precipice' does not have a negative connotation as far as my understanding goes. If not, what other words or phrases can substitute 'precipice' in the given sentence?

> *On Wednesday, Dimitrov beat Murray in a straight-sets quarterfinal, lifting himself to the precipice of his first Grand Slam final.*

Comment: One of the words used in the definition of [*precipice*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precipice) is *brink*  try substituting that.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for the answer. I have changed my question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: It also means very dangerous situation. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/precipice I think it talks about this meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "lifting himself to the precipice", I think he means Dimitrov has raised himself up to a new level—to the top of a cliff, so to speak—but his new position is precarious because the "big four" are up there (or something like that; I didn't read it carefully), and he risks being knocked back down again.

Sports reporters often use big words in strange (and often incorrect) ways. It's just something that they do.